# Add rows to a table dynamically in existing word document using OpenXml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, tabular

I'm using OpenXml for working with word documents. Now I have two tables in my word document (docx) width headers, now I need to add dynamic rows to these tables.

Comment: I have not tried anything for adding rows, i don't know which approach to use.

Answer (score 14):

Alright this should help you. I'm sure there are  other ways of adding rows to an existing table, but this is the one I use.

I'm assuming in this example, that your table header is exatcly 1 row. And in this example I've put a bookmark called "table" inside my table in Word. It doesn't really matter where in the table, seeing as I'm digging out through Parent until I arrive at the table.

My original word document:
[image: picture of table before processing]

Code with comments explaining it:

```
//setup
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\test\cb\exptable.docx", true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    var document = mainPart.Document;
    var bookmarks = document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();

    //find bookmark
    var myBookmark = bookmarks.First(bms => bms.Name == "table");
    //dig through parent until we hit a table
    var digForTable = myBookmark.Parent;
    while(!(digForTable is Table))
    {
        digForTable = digForTable.Parent;
    }
    //get rows
    var rows = digForTable.Descendants<TableRow>().ToList();
    //remember you have a header, so keep row 1, clone row 2 (our template for dynamic entry)
    var myRow = (TableRow)rows.Last().Clone();
    //remove it after cloning.
    rows.Last().Remove();
    //do stuf with your row and insert it in the table
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //clone our "reference row"
        var rowToInsert = (TableRow)myRow.Clone();
        //get list of cells
        var listOfCellsInRow = rowToInsert.Descendants<TableCell>().ToList();
        //just replace every bit of text in cells with row-number for this example
        foreach(TableCell cell in listOfCellsInRow)
        {
            cell.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault().Text = i.ToString();
        }
        //add new row to table, after last row in table
        digForTable.Descendants<TableRow>().Last().InsertAfterSelf(rowToInsert);
    }
}
```

Document after running code:
[image]

That should do the trick.

Comment: Can i  solve this problem without any trick? And How can i directly access to table inside word document?

Comment: Table table = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().First();                                                                                                                                                      this code snippet finds the first table inside word document, using this way i can find second, third tables, can't i?

Comment: ... Yes ? I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, could you use my answer? Yes, you can use your code snippet to find the first table, given that it is a child of Body. If it is inside a paragraph or something else, and not a direct child, you can use Descendants<Table>, like I do in my example.